# Delete tables from database Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ddl, database-administration

I have deleted some tables from an Oracle 10g database using the `drop` command.

When I list the tables using `select * from cat;` I get the following :

[image: Tables list]

Are the tables deleted or not? Why do I have these `BIN$...` things? How can I remove them or the tables once and for all?

Thanks!

Comment: @DavidAldridge gave the right answer.  As an aside, though, you should really avoid using the old, depricated data dictionary views like `tab` or `cat`.  They exist for backwards compatibility and aren't being enhanced as new features get added.  So they don't tend to play well when Oracle introduces the recycle bin or new obect types.  `all_tables` or `all_objects` would be much more logical data dictionary tables to query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are entries in the Recycle Bin, created by the deletion of a table.

They can be purged if required.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables011.htm

Answer (score 2):

The tables prefixed with `BIN$` are tables placed in the recycle bin for easy recovery. You can completely remove them by purging it. Either specifically per table:

```
PURGE TABLE BIN$ABCDEFG;
```

Or for the entire recycle bin at once:

```
PURGE RECYCLEBIN;
```

Answer (score 1):

once you drop tables , they go to recyle bin for tempopary time in case you can to get them back ( by flashback for example) with time they diseapear , and if you want to remove at all you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/tables.htm#ADMIN01511):

> When you drop a table, **the database does not immediately remove the
>   space associated with the table**. The database **renames the table and
>   places it and any associated objects in a recycle bin**, where, in case
>   the table was dropped in error, it can be recovered at a later time.
>   This feature is called Flashback Drop, and the FLASHBACK TABLE
>   statement is used to restore the table. Before discussing the use of
>   the FLASHBACK TABLE statement for this purpose, it is important to
>   understand how the recycle bin works, and how you manage its contents.

To delete pernamently use [PURGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9003.htm#sthref8763)

> Specify **PURGE** if you want to drop the table and release the space
>   associated with it in a single step. If you specify PURGE, then the
>   database does not place the table and its dependent objects into the
>   recycle bin.

```
PURGE TABLE BIN$jsleilx392mk2=293$0;
```

> Users can purge the recycle bin of their own objects, and release
>   space for objects, by using the following statement:

```
PURGE RECYCLEBIN;
```